# Changed section from Channel to Structure, but can't re-order entries

Tags: structure, sections, channels

As the title says, I changed a section from Channel to Structure, but when clicking on that section in the dashboard, the layout still looks like a Channel, and I'm not able to reorder/drag the entries.

I've tried switching the section back to a Channel, and then again back to a Structure, with no change. Most of the entries were added since switching over to Structure, but they all still behave like Channel entries.

Comment: Good to know you can do that. No problems at all after changing the section type?

Comment: Nope, no problems so far. I'd guess that you might lose the hierarchy/order data if you switched from Structure to Channel, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Might be the case. And you better don't change it to Single :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you switched sorting to "Structure"?

[image: sort menu]

When you're not sorting by Structure, you won't be able to rearrange the entries.

Comment: Oh man I feel so dumb. Thank you so much for this answer. It looks like as of Craft 2.5 you can arrange by Title, URI, author, as well as structure order.

Comment: I just encountered the same thing but when I change back to Structure all the nesting is lost?

Comment: lol, 7 years later, same problem, same solution.

Comment: I can't believe I still get caught out by this one