# Structure not allowing me to nest

Tags: entries, structure

I have a Structure Section, with the following settings:

- Entries in this section have their own URLs = Checked
- Entry URL Format = recommendations/{slug} & {parent.uri}/{slug}
- Max Levels = 2

This worked for the first few entries (both Parent and Child) I created but after saving and returning to the Structure page (from Entries), the entries are no longer nested and the 'move' icon is missing. And, 'Create a new child entry' is created but also not nested when created.

Another Structure Section I have set up is working correctly.

I've tried clearing both browser and Craft cache. Not sure else what to try.

Craft CMS 2.6.2949

Comment: OK. I can replicate the issue. Go to Entries > Structures select all from the checkbox. 'Set status' to Enabled. 'Statuses updated.' message. Childen / nesting / move icon lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/changed-section-from-channel-to-structure-but-cant-re-order-entries

Comment: Oh my goodness. I never even knew this was a thing! I'm tempted to delete my post to hide my shame :-0

Comment: Lol, it's okay. The confusion comes up often enough, it's better to have multiple avenues for people to find the correct information. :)